# Плавный горизонтальный скрол <div> блоков (бегущая строка), на базе Owl carousel 2

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Имею 20 блоков с фразами, необходимо организовать плавную горизонтальную прокрутку, с права на лево, на данный момент сделал owl carousel 2 c такими опциями
    `$("#carusel").owlCarousel({
            items: 5,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 1000,
            smartSpeed:1000,
            autoplayHoverPause: true
        }
    );`

Все бы ничего, но стандартный скрол Owl-a имеет ускорение в начале и в конце, что делает прокрутку рывками, что посоветуете сделать, для "линейной" прокрутки?

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается есть опция `slideTransition: 'linear'`, которая и делает то что мне нужно, вопрос закрыт.